# Silverlight - Load XAML file via C# (just like in the WinForms days) - How?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

So I'm new to SL coming from a WinForms background where I could instantiate a UserControl or Form like this:

```
MyForm frm = new MyForm();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

So in SL, I created a simple Page.xaml and a second xaml file called Page2.xaml - I dropped a button in the Page.xaml file and within that button's click event, I tried adding the following to call the 2nd xaml file:

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Page2 frm2 = new Page2();
    frm2.  // ?? don't know what write here ??
}
```

How can I call XAML UserControls?

Answer (score 1):

In order to navigate to a completely different silverlight page you will need a "container" usercontrol with your main page inside of it.  From there you can set your internal UserControl like so:

```
insideControl = new Page2();
```

For more information:
http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=56933

Comment: Great, I did the following and was able to load my form:

    this.Content = new Page2();

But not exactly what I'm looking for.  I would like for Page2() to come up as a "subform", i.e. sort of as a modal form.  How can I do this?

Comment: You could use the popup control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ChildWindow.Xaml and create instance of child control in Mainpage.xaml

```
ChildWindow chw = new ChildWindow();
chw.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in silverlight what you actually need to do is Navigate to a separate page.

It is a web platform so Navigate is the web form of winforms. show() method.

Answer (score 0):

The [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) class has been developped exactly for that purpose. Using its Load or Parse methods will return you the objects that would have been generated by your Xaml.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a UserControl.xaml that is tehe container from page.xaml and page2.xaml

this container have a grid with x:Name="miGrid"
:

< Grid x:Name="miGrid" />

after you load in childrens of this control the instance of user control in this case frm2..

miGrid.Childrens.Clear();
miGrid.Childrens.Add(frm2);